# Is it possible to show windows phone 7 device information on Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7

Hi i am learning  windows phone 7. Can any body tell me the way  to display, windows phone 7 
device information on Emulator.

Comment: please be more sepcific in what you're trying to do / what "device information" you're after.

Comment: I want to display windows 7 phone device information on emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a good place to start with Device info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394037(VS.92).aspx

Thanks!